# websocket-client python no data from the binance api

Tags: python, websocket

I had the problem that the websocket didn't respond and there was no data coming. Empty terminal without anything printed out.

I downgraded the python websocket-client to 0.57.0 version and now I am getting 'close' printed out but still no messages coming in.

I have no idea about what is wrong. Any clue why?

```js
import websocket

cc = 'btcusdt'
interval = '1m'
socket = f'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/{cc}@kline_{interval}'

def on_close(ws):
    print('close')


def on_message(ws, message):
    print('message')
    print(message)


ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
    socket,
    on_message=on_message,
    on_close=on_close)

websocket.enableTrace(True)

ws.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me ... it printed messages
you might have in import problem, try reinstalling python with all the packages, or make sure you are using the correct