# Websocket-client functions on_open and on_message don't recognise websocket object on vscode

Tags: python, websocket

I am having a trouble getting some data from Binance Websocket.

The code is the following:

```
import websocket

cc = "btcusdt"
interval = "1m"

socket = f"wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/{cc}@kline_{interval}"
#print(socket)

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")


ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket,on_message=on_message, on_close=on_close)
ws.run_forever()
```

When I run this program on vscode it does not print anything on the screen and it seems like the `ws` inside the `on_open` and `on_message` functions is not recognised.

Although when I use Google Colab and run the same code it runs just fine and it prints the data on the screen.

I can not understand why it doesn't work on my vscode.

Any ideas and solutions would be  appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579991/websocket-client-python-no-data-from-the-binance-api

Comment: @toyotaSupra I tried reinstalling the `websocket-client` and nothing changed. I will do the same with python. I hope it will work. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I don't used vscode.

Comment: @toyotaSupra ok but can this be a vscode problem?

Comment: If u have python on vscode or c++ on vscode. will work. Converted to vscode. will work ..U can google websocket using vscode.

Comment: Here is RFC6455.  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455.html

Comment: @toyotaSupra i have installed all python extensions so it should be working. Anyway I will try to reinstall it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install these two libraries

```
pip3 install websocket-client[test]
```

and

```
pip3 install rel
```